# In javadoc, what is the difference between the tags @throws and @exception?

Tags: java, javadoc

Take the following implementation of a array-based stack of chars for example:

```java
public char peek() throws Underflow {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        return stack[pos];
    } else {
        throw new Underflow("Peeking at an empty stack.");
    }
}
```

Back when I'm using just a text editor, I always use the `@exception`-tag, but now my IDE (NetBeans) used `@throws` when generating the JavaDoc.

So my question is, what is the difference between the two and when should one be preferred over another (using the above code for example)?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There is none, they're synonyms.

From [the docs](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#throwstag):

> *Documenting Exceptions with `@throws` Tag
>
> NOTE - The tags `@throws` and `@exception` are synonyms.*

Comment: Hmmm in that case why did Sun provide two ways to document exceptions?

Comment: @jon2512chua: [`@exception` came first](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@exception), but then (and this is complete speculation) I think someone felt that was over-long and also didn't tie up nicely with Java's `throws` keyword, so they added `@throws`. It would be *very* early, though, I think they were both there when I started using Java in 1995. I've almost never seen `@exception` used in the wild, there seems to be a clear preference for `@throws` in the community.

Comment: I wonder why does `@throws` end with an "s" but `@return` doesn't.

Comment: @Pang: Because human beings are chaotic. :-) `return` fits better with `param` (e.g., it's describing the return value, it's describing the parameter), and indeed with the original `@exception`. But then parallel construction went out the window with `@throws`. :-)

Answer (score 20):

`@throws` was added because it is a keyword ("throws" clause in a method declaration),

and, as a verb, it is just more natural to read. This reads as a sentence:

```java
@throws NullPointerException
```

while this seem more redundant:

```java
@exception NullPointerException
```

Otherwise, both are synonyms

Answer (score 9):

`@exception` isn't 100% correct if you code throws a `Throwable`. `@throws` is more exact. (I realize there isn't a good use case for ever using `throw new Throwable()`, but theoretically it is allowed.)

Comment: `Error`s are also `Throwable`s that are not `Exception`s. You don't usually throw them manually, but I've already written a couple of `throw new AssertionError()`.