# Javadoc, " exception not thrown" in Eclipse

Tags: java, javadoc

When creating a javaodc, you describe the exceptions your methods can throw, right?

Take a look at the examlple:

```
public  void createLogFile() {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        MainScene.ausgabeText.setText("Fehler bei dem Erstellen des Log Files.");

    }
}
```

That is my javadoc for this method.

```
/**
 * A logfile will be created
 * @exception IOException
 *                When the log file coulndt be created ( just a test :-))
 */
```

When exporting to a javadoc, Eclipse tells me:

```
error: exception not thrown: java.io.IOException
 * @exception IOException
```

But Eclipse wants me to catch that Exception.

Why is my Eclipse giving me the error message above?

Comment: @ernest_k Eclipse is giving me the same Error message with (@)throws

Comment: Add the exception to the method's `throws` clause: `public  void createLogFile() throws IOException`

Comment: The message is correct. The code does not throws an exception - you try-catch it.

Comment: @ernest_k What do you mean by that?

Comment: @piradian How should i write my javadoc then?

Comment: If you does not throw an exception you should not add it to javadoc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write a method, the implementation is hidden from the caller (ignore the fact that you can see the method implementation if you yourself wrote it). Sometimes in your implementation of a method, you will encounter exceptions (or you might even throw custom exceptions). There are two things you can do:

#### Catch

You can catch an exception when you *want* to handle it. That means that you know something *could* go wrong and you know what to do so that the program can continue in a predictable manner if that happens.

Since the caller cannot see your implementation, it is totally hidden from them.

#### Throws

When you do not want to handle the exception, because it is *more suitable* for the caller to be aware of this problem and handle it. In this case, you do not `catch` it and adds that `Exception` to the method via `throws` keyword. When you do this, you *may* add a `@throws` or `@exception` annotation in the method Javadoc to tell the caller exactly when they would expect to receive the particular exception.

Since that annotation only serves to tell the caller when to expect and how to properly handle the exception thrown by the method, then it is pointless to add any exception that is not thrown by the method.

Note that you are only required to `throws` checked exceptions. Methods do not need to list the unchecked exceptions via `throws`, as they are usually caused by poorly written codes.

Answer (score 4):

There is 2 way to deal with `Exception`:

1. Catch it inside the method, outside the method no-one will know that an Exception occurs, and so you `can't write in the Javadoc` that this metho will throw an Exception (implicitly *throws outside*)

   ```
   /**
   */
   public void createLogFile() {
       try {
           //...
       } catch (IOException e) {
           //...   
       }
   }
   ```
2. You let the Exception propagates outside your method, and in that case you `can writ in the Javadoc` that this method can throws an Exception (implicitly *throws outside*)

   ```
   /**
   * @throws IOException When the log file coulndt be created
   */
   public void createLogFile() throws IOException  {
      //...
   }
   ```

---

<sub>*As a note : the tags `@throws` and `@exception` are synonyms. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510170/in-javadoc-what-is-the-difference-between-the-tags-throws-and-exception#answers)*</sub>

Comment: So if i catch the exception( like in my case), i should NOT write anything in my javadoc?

Comment: @ErwinIvanov yes exactly, because the Javadoc gives information on HOW to use the method, and because no IOException will come from this method you shouldn't write it

Comment: @ErwinIvanov Yes. `@exception` annotation is used together with `... throws SomethingException`. When you catch an exception, you are handling it. When you `throws` it, you are asking the caller to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

The function should throws Exception which you define in javadoc comment. Actually you are not throwing an IOException. You are catching it.

```
public  void createLogFile() throws IOException {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        MainScene.ausgabeText.setText("Fehler bei dem Erstellen des Log Files.");

    }
}
```

Comment: Should i do anything in my javadoc, when catching?

Comment: Your code seems impossible, because if catching, impossible to propagate it ;)

Comment: No you dont need to add exception case when catching.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't include `IOException` to Javadocs `@throws` clauses because you never throw one.

Apparently, Eclipse tries to make sure that the list of the method `throws` clause matches the list in Javadocs.

```
 // valid
 /**
  * ...
  * @throws IOException description
  */
 void createLogFile() throws IOException { ... }

 // invalid
 /**
  * ...
  * @throws IOException description
  */
 void createLogFile() { ... }

 // bad documentation
 /**
  * ...
  */
 void createLogFile() throws IOException { ... }
```

Consider the narrative style for your documentation. Instead of "A logfile will be created", you could say "Creates a logfile".